# Why is my repository using the primary entity manager?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have been stuck trying to get multiple datasources hooked up with spring boot with a couple custom query implementations. When I call those customized queries the correct entity manager is used however when I use the basic crudrepository functions, it uses the primary manager and produces "Not a managed type" error.

Here are my two sources config:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name="DB1")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(primaryDataSource())
                .persistenceUnit("primary")
                .packages("com.company.monitoring.db.primary")
                .build();
    }
```

and

```
 @Configuration
 public class AuditLogDataSourceConfig {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "auditlog")
    @Bean(name="DB2")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="auditlog.datasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "secondary")
    @Qualifier("secondaryEntityManager")
    @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(secondaryDataSource())
                .persistenceUnit("secondary")
                .packages("com.company.monitoring.db.secondary" )
                .build();
    }

}
```

Repo in controller that uses the wrong datasource:

```
import com.company.monitoring.db.secondary.repository.FileAuditLogDAO;
...
@RequestMapping("/eventdetails/")
public class EventDetailsController {
...

    @Autowired
    private FileAuditLogDAO repository;
...
```

FileAuditLogDAO is in package com.company.monitoring.db.secondary.repository 
and FileAuditLogEntity is in package com.company.monitoring.db.secondary.entity.

I know the primary is being used since when I add `"com.company.monitoring.db.secondary"` to the primarys packages I no longer get the *Not a managed type: class com.company.monitoring.db.secondary.entity.FileAuditLogEntity*. I have tried various places for @EnableJPARepositories with no success. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Never done that, but AFAIK, you need two different EnableJpaRepositories annotations, and they should both specify their specific basePackage[Classe]s and their entityManagerFactoryRef.

Comment: Where in your code do you believe you specified that `EventDetailsController` and/or `FileAuditLogDAO` should use the `secondaryEntityManager`?

Comment: @Andreas  I thought when I specified in the packages method of the entity manager factory including the package of the repository with FileAuditLogDAO. But that is not the case

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.Builder.html#packages-java.lang.String...-: *The names of packages to scan for @Entity annotations*. It has nothing to do with spring-data-jpa repositories.